# Unable to install yarn due to openssl error on mac

Tags: openssl, yarnpkg, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to install the latest version of Yarn using asdf on my mac and getting the error below. I recently upgraded to the Big Sur OS. I'm a relatively new coder and don't know much about what could be going wrong with ssl on an install like this, so any help figuring out what the problem is would be appreciated.

```
Lumen@Lauras-Air ~ % asdf install yarn 1.22.17
--2021-11-10 15:12:19--  https://classic.yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.22.17/yarn-v1.22.17.tar.gz
Resolving classic.yarnpkg.com (classic.yarnpkg.com)... 138.197.207.178, 138.68.234.180
Connecting to classic.yarnpkg.com (classic.yarnpkg.com)|138.197.207.178|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```